# How to add default signature and new tables in a new outlook mail by testcomplete

Tags: vbscript, outlook, testcomplete

I am trying to send new outlook mail by testcomplete using vb scripting language .In that new mail i want to add new tables and keep default signature at bottom of  mail by testcomplete.  i am getting VB script run time error when i am using this code..please check the code and suggest me the correct methods i have to use to add new tables and signature

```
Function SendMail()
Dim objOutLook, NamespaceMAPI,objNewMail, fso, SendReceiveControls
Dim strTo,strCc ,strBcc ,strSubject, AccountName,strAttachmentPath

strSubject="test"
strTo=yyy@yy.com
strCc=XXX@XX.com
strBcc =zzz@zzz.com
strAttachmentPath="c:\text.txt"

Set objOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
Set NamespaceMAPI = objOutLook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objNewMail = objOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
objOutLook.DisplayAlerts =True  
objNewMail.TO = strTo
objNewMail.CC = strCc
objNewMail.BCC=strBcc
objNewMail.Subject = strSubject
objNewMail.Body = strMsg

If strAttachmentPath <> "" Then 
Set fso =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(strAttachmentPath) Then
    objNewMail.Attachments.Add(strAttachmentPath)
    objNewMail.GetDefaultsignature()               'script run time error occured here

    objNewMail.addtable(4,3)
    objNewMail.display

Else 
    msgbox "Attachment File Does not exists"
End If  
End If


objOutLook.Quit

''''''' Releasing objects '''''''
Set objOutLook =Nothing 
Set objNewMail = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

please help me.. thanks in advannce....

Comment: Your code says you get a runtime error. Since we're not psychic you need to show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56307/) or [this](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56308/#CDO) helps. They are alternative methods to yours.
I prefer to use the 2nd option, the CDO method, you just need to take atention to the fact that usually this email goes to the spam inbox, you need to manually add it to your secure contacts

Comment: I have to use outlook only to send outlookmails by testcomplete,so i wont use CDO method, my outlook mails are going to inbox only.can we add tables and signature to new mail?please suggest me

Comment: Try to write html into "mMessage.HTMLBody"-> http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56308/#Outlook

Check html syntax:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp